# Dynamic Configuration Reload in Spring Boot 3 Application

Tags: spring, yaml, spring-boot-3

I have built a Spring Boot 3 application that reads a set of data from a YAML file. In this file, I have an 'enable' tag that can be set to either 'true' or 'false'. If it's set to 'true', the application accesses the data from the set, and if it's 'false', the application cannot access those data.I am hoping solution that does not involve spring cloud

```
request:
  endpoints:
    - url: "https://test.com"
      enabled: true
      rt: [ "2", "5", "7", "9",
            "1000", "1001", "1002"
      ]
```

Currently, every time I change the 'enable' tag, I need to restart the application for the changes to take effect. I am looking for a dynamic solution that would allow the application to detect changes in the YAML file and perform operations accordingly, without needing to restart the application.

Thank you.

I tried to find solution online but could not find yet.

Comment: In fact Spring Cloud would be the best way to handle this I think. Also you can just create another simple service to handle and to provide these data via api call.  that would be also a good way.